# How to check data connection

Tags: android

Thanks for previous replies,

I tried to check the data connection through code, I used

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
    return true;
    } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
        /*
         * check.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
         * check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); noInterntet.setText("");
         */
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

But this code check the data availability from android version 1.6, when i run this code in 1.5, it never check the data availability, i always return true even i disabled GPRS and Wifi. is there anything other than this to check the data availability. Dont know where i made mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want 'isAvailable' rather than 'isConnected'? You could also query the enable state of the devices, i.e. WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()

I suspect that your 1.5 device simply misreports the availablity state. I would question the need to work on 1.5 since there are very few real world devices using it. I can only think of the years-old G1 and Magic phones for which 1.6 updates were made available.